# Refactor small Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

I have this small code

```
class ReadReportService
  def self.get_oldest_reports(count, filter={})
    reports = Report.unread.order('created_at DESC').limit(count)

    reports = reports.where(category: filter[:category]) if filter[:category].present?
    reports = reports.where(cost: filter[:cost]) if filter[:cost].present?
    reports = reports.where(email: filter[:email]) if filter[:email].present?

    reports.update_all(status: Report.statuses[:read])

    reports.to_a
  end
end
```

Can I do this better and nicer? How Can I improve check hash parameters present?

Answer (score 0):

it should be in `Report` model:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUSES = {read: 'read', pending: 'pending'}

  scope :ordered_limit, ->(limit) { order('created_at DESC').limit(limit) }
  scope :filter_category, ->(category) { where(category: category) if category }
  scope :filter_cost, ->(cost) { where(cost: cost) if cost }
  scope :filter_email, ->(email) { where(email: email) if email }

  def self.get_oldest_reports(count, filter={})
    reports = unread.ordered_limit(count)
      .filter_category(filter[:category])
      .filter_cost(cost)
      .filter_email(email)
    reports.update_all(status: STATUSES[:read])

    reports.to_a # not sure you need it
  end
end
```

Comment: I need this as as Service, because my class have more def ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you want to simplify code that works with filters:

```
reports = Report.unread.order('created_at DESC').limit(count)
[:category, :cost, :email].each do |key|
  reports = reports.where(key => filter[key]) if filter[key].present?
end
reports.update_all(status: Report.statuses[:read])
reports.to_a
```

And, by the way, it's not good idea to call `update_all` in method named `get_xxx`. If I'm getting something I'm not expecting that something will be changed.

P.S. If you like oneliners you can even do something like this:

```
reports.where(filter.slice(:category, :cost, :email).select { |k, v| v.present? })
```